# How to Skip Validations w/ find_or_create_by_?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

Is it possible to skip validations with a dynamic find/create by method?

For example with regular save I can do something like:

```
p = Post.new
p.title = nil
p.body = nil
p.save(:validate => false)
```

Would love to do the same with `find_or_create_by_title`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It dosnt look possible with the [code in Rails right now](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/827e5de60f27c6b559640eda7b79857050a72d9e/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L251) however you may have better luck being a little more verbose in how you write the code. You can use `find_or_initialize_by_` which creates a new object but does not save it. You can then call save with your custom options, also in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) they have a neat demonstration that is hard to find so I will include it below:

```
# No 'Winter' tag exists
winter = Tag.find_or_initialize_by_name("Winter")
winter.new_record? # true
```

Good luck and let me know if you need more pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That's the way i've gone!   Appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 6):

For some cases, `find_or_initialize_by_` will not be useful and need to skip validations with `find_or_create_by`.

For this, you can use below alternative flow and method of ROR:

Update your model like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :skip_validation
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :title, unless: :skip_validation
end
```

You can use it now like this:
 `Post.where(user_id: self.id).first_or_create!(skip_validation: true)`

I have used `first_or_create` instead of `find_or_create_by` here. You can pass more column names and values with this, and your validation will not be worked with this.

- You can continue without any changes for strong parameters end and no need to permit this 'skip_validation' so it will work with validations while adding entries.
- Using this, you can use it with and without validations by passing a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Currently skipping validation **DOES** work with find_or_create_by.

For example, running:

```
  Contact.find_or_create_by(email: "hello@corsego.com).save(validate: false)
```

will skip a validation like:

```
  validates :name, :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```